# Как в Thymeleaf задать условие на изменение background в <li>?

Tags: веб-программирование, spring, thymeleaf

Контроллер на страницу передает массив чисел/pages ближайших страниц и id текущей страницы.
Пробегаясь по массиву pages я отображаю все возможные ссылки на страницы.
Задача состоит в создании условия if(page == id) то th:style="buckground:#ffffff;" -  Как это можно реализовать ? Нужный кусок кода -

```
 <li class="page-item" th:each="page : ${pages}"><a class="page-link" th:href="@{/snowy/page/{id}(id=${page})}" th:text="${page}">number</a></li>
```

Полный код код NavBar -

```
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        <li class="page-item" >
            <a class="page-link" th:href="@{'/snowy/page/' + ${id -1}}" tabindex="-1" th:if="${(id - 1 ) > 0}">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item" th:each="page : ${pages}"><a class="page-link" th:href="@{/snowy/page/{id}(id=${page})}" th:text="${page}">number</a></li>
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" th:href="@{'/snowy/page/' + ${id + 1}}" th:if="${(id + 1 ) <= maxPage}">Next</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать условие непосредственно внутри выражения:

```
th:style="${ (page == id) ? 'background:#ffffff;' : null }"
```

В итоге получается:

```
<li class="page-item" th:each="page : ${pages}" th:style="${ (page == id) ? 'background:#ffffff;' : null }">
    <a class="page-link" th:href="@{/snowy/page/{id}(id=${page})}" th:text="${page}">number</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!